# Examining programming laboratory exercise for faculty

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm developing software for examining programming laboratory exercise for faculty. I have an `Error` object that can be attached to students work. It can be attached to class implementation (mark code in .java file as error), to class itself (student didn't implement something required) or to the whole solution (something like bad practice error).

```
public enum RemarkType {
    ERROR, WARNING
}

public enum RemarkBinding {
    FILE_SPECIFIC, TASK_SPECIFIC, ASSIGNMENT_SPECIFIC
}

public class RemarksFactory {       
    public static ErrorRemark createErrorRemark(StudentAssignment studentAssignment,
            StudentTask task, TaskFile taskFile, ExaminerError error,
            String markedCode, int percentage, int startRow, int endRow,
            String explanation) {
        return new ErrorRemark(studentAssignment, task, taskFile, error, markedCode,
                percentage, startRow, endRow, explanation);
    }

    public static WarningRemark createWarningRemark(StudentAssignment student,
            StudentTask task, TaskFile taskFile, String markedCode,
            int startRow, int endRow, String explanation) {
        return new WarningRemark(student, task, taskFile, markedCode,
                startRow, endRow, explanation);
    }
}

public class ErrorRemark {        
    private ExaminerError error;
    private int errorValue;
    private StudentAssignment studentAssignment;
    private StudentTask studentTask;
    private TaskFile taskFile;
    private String explanation;
    private int startRow;
    private int endRow;
    private String markedCode;

    ErrorRemark(StudentAssignment student, StudentTask task, TaskFile taskFile,
                ExaminerError error, String markedCode, int percentage, int startRow,
                int endRow, String explanation) {
            if (startRow > endRow) {
                log.error("startRow(" + startRow
                        + ") row must be less than or equal to endRow(" + endRow
                        + ")");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            setError(error);
            setStudentAssignment(studentAssignment);
            setStudentTask(task);
            setTaskFile(taskFile);
            setMarkedCode(markedCode);
            setPercentage(percentage);
            setExplanation(explanation);

            if (getBinding() == RemarkBinding.FILE_SPECIFIC) {
                setStartRow(startRow);
                setEndRow(endRow);
            } else {
                setStartRow(DEFAULT_ROW);
                setEndRow(DEFAULT_ROW);
            }
        }

    public ExaminerError getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(ExaminerError error) {
        if (error == null) {
            log.error("error must not be null");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        this.error = error;
    }

    public int getErrorValue() {
        return errorValue;
    }


    public void setErrorValue(int errorValue) {
        this.errorValue = errorValue;
    }

    public StudentAssignment getStudent() {
        return studentAssignment;
    }


    public void setStudentAssignment(StudentAssignment studentAssignment) {
        if (studentAssignment== null) {
            log.error("student must not be null");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        this.studentAssignment = studentAssignment;
    }

    public Task getTask() {
        return studentTask.getTask();
    }

    public StudentTask getStudentTask() {
        return studentTask;
    }

    public void setStudentTask(StudentTask studentTask) {
        this.studentTask = studentTask;
    }

    public TaskFile getTaskFile() {
        return taskFile;
    }

    public void setTaskFile(TaskFile taskFile) {
        this.taskFile = taskFile;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return error.getName();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return error.getDescription();
    }

    public String getExplanation() {
        return explanation;
    }

    public void setExplanation(String explanation) {
        this.explanation = explanation == null || "".equals(explanation) ? Remark.DEFAULT_EXPLANATION
                : explanation;
    }

    public RemarkBinding getBinding() {
        if (studentTask == null && taskFile == null) {
            return RemarkBinding .ASSIGNMENT_SPECIFIC;
        } else if (taskFile == null) {
            return RemarkBinding .TASK_SPECIFIC;
        } else {
            return RemarkBinding .FILE_SPECIFIC;
        }
    }

    public String getMarkedCode() {
        return markedCode;
    }

    public void setMarkedCode(String markedCode) {
        this.markedCode = markedCode == null || "".equals(markedCode) ? Remark.DEFAULT_MARKED_CODE
                : markedCode;
    }

    public int getStartRow() {
        return startRow;
    }

    public void setStartRow(int startRow) {
        this.startRow = startRow;
    }

    public int getEndRow() {
        return endRow;
    }

    public void setEndRow(int endRow) {
        this.endRow = endRow;
    }

    public RemarkType getType() {
        return RemarkType.ERROR;
    }

    public int compareTo(Remark o) {
        if (o == null)
            return 1;

        if (getStartRow() < o.getStartRow()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (getStartRow() > o.getStartRow()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (getEndRow() < o.getEndRow()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (getEndRow() > o.getEndRow()) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        result += "Error:\r\n" + error + "\r\n";
        result += "Marked code:\r\n" + markedCode + "\r\n\r\n";
        result += "Explanation: \r\n\t" + explanation + "\r\n";
        return result;
    }   
}
```

The only difference between `ErrorRemark` and `WarningRemark` is that warning's error attribute is null (warning has no error).

As you can see, it has a lot of parameters.  If error is not attached to file (code in .java file), then attributes like start row, end row and marked code are unused.

The biggest problem for me is that error can be attached to three different things, which creates a lot of combinations and messy code.

Comment: So, `WarningRemark` is an essentially copy-and-pasted from `ErrorRemark`?

Comment: Yes... On to do list is to remove that class completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of quick remarks:

---

You could consider using your `RemarkType` enum to use alongside a general `Remark` class. In the end, the only difference between a *Warning* and an *Error* is exactly that: a different severity level. If you have any case-specific logic then you can add those methods to the enum itself.

This would save you from having pretty much the same classes for `ErrorRemark` and `WarningRemark`.

---

You're doing validation inside the constructor instead of the corresponding setters. If I want to, I can create an object that has a startrow less than the endrow but then manually use the setters afterwards to change it anyway.

---

You're throwing a `NullPointerException`. Big no-no. What you want to throw is an `IllegalArgumentException`, much more intuitive. When we catch that exception, we want to catch all invalid arguments; not just those that happen to be `null`. And it would cause confusion if we receive NPE's from somewhere else.

---

You have an `int errorValue`. This doesn't quite tell me anything, consider using an enum to clarify what each value means in human language (if applicable ofcourse, maybe it is domain-specific).

---

Are you sure those setters should all be `public`? I would expect a `Remark` object to be definitive.

---

You implement the `compareTo(Remark o)` method but you are not implementing the interface, essentially rendering it useless. Add `implements Comparable<Remark>` to your class declaration.

---

Use platform independent newline constants instead of manually adding `\r\n`: `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: I would up-vote your answer but no reputation :)
Variable errorValue is used for some later calculations.
Setters should not all be public, working on that refactor.
As for the start row and end row, there is setPositio(startRow, endRow) instead of separate methods, though it's private now too :)

Useful advises, thank you. Any comment on number of parameters?

Comment: If you need all those parameters then you'll always have them in one place or the other. You could think about extracting them to a separate class but that's really just moving the "problem" to somewhere else and might complicate validation.

Comment: What do you think about extracting common base class Remark and deriving into AssignmentRemark, TaskRemark and FileRemark?

Base Remark would contain ExaminerError error, String explanation variables, AssignmentRemark would add StudentAssignment variable, TaskRemark - StudentTask variable, and FileRemark - TaskFile, start row and end row variables... Would change factory to support creations of all Remarks?

Comment: What's the difference between every subclass? Why not just add one extra parameter `RemarkType` (which I would rename to `Severity`)?

Comment: Severity defines if student needs to be penalized for that Remark. Subclass would define to what is Error attached to - solution in general, class in general, or class implementation where code is marked as error

Comment: Thing that worries me about subclassing, is later checks and casts depending on Remark type.

Comment: Since Java 7, you can/should use http://stackoverflow.com/a/10937340/2115680